# What should do to become efficient programmer?

Tags: coding-style

I want to ask how to make code efficient by reducing loops and to make simple and short.What should I do means what should i refer to become efficient coder.

Comment: how about learning Computer Science & Maths?

Comment: I am learning computer engineering but i am saying that is it another platform or way on which i can increase my coding efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus on learning algorithms first. Try to read "The Pragmatic Programmer" book.
Every programming language is optimized for a specific purpose and knowing basic algorithms would make the learning curve more gentle.